# mysql not updating in a while statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to extract two fields from tables accesscode and student the update  the table borrowers with the data that i have extracted from the previous tables.

```
$q=$db->query("SELECT regnum,  accesscode FROM student,student_accesscode WHERE student.id=student_accesscode.studentid");


while($qd=$q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$access=$qd['accesscode'];
$regnum=$qd['regnum'];  
$q2=$db->exec("UPDATE borrowers SET cardnumber='$access' WHERE cardnumber='$regnum'");
if($q2)
{
echo $access.'          '. $regnum.'<br/>';     
}
else
{
echo'erro....<br/>';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried running the select query in MySQL Workbench or HeidiSQL?

Comment: Instead of just saying what's _not_ happening, try explaining what _is_. What output are you getting? Have you checked the values of `$access` and `$regnum`? Have you checked to see if you are even getting inside of the `while` loop?

Comment: yes the values $access and $regnum are displaying values. But the table is borrowers is not updating though. tony the i tried the select query and produced results

Answer (score 0):

Appending `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);` before `$db->query()` probably gives you an Exception...

Prior to the `$db->setAttribute`, you will get this:

```
PDO::prepare(): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.
```

So, instead of `fetch()`, use `fetchAll()` with `foreach` loop, it will make you less insane.

Ref. from [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
For a statement that you need to issue multiple times, prepare a PDOStatement 
object with PDO::prepare() and issue the statement with PDOStatement::execute().
```

From the PHP exec page at http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php

I don't know if this is the problem, I always use `prepare` and `execute`. It could just be for performance reasons. Something to try anyway.